# Display and image on when a button is clicked (resubmission)

Tags: html, image, button, onclick

The page (http://www.squishypig.com/ft/uploads/) has an upload script (below) I want to be able to show a loading image when the user hits submit to submit the files.

Here is the code in question:

```
<td width="500">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<center>
<p>
<table>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="white">
<form action="/cgi-bin/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="File" name="FILE1">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE2">
<p>`
<input type="File" name="FILE3">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE4">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE5">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE6">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE7">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE8">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE9">
<p>
<input type="File" name="FILE10">
<p>

<input type="Submit" value="submit">

</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

I want to display a 'loading' image on click of the submit button, but still leaving the old function behind (Upload).

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: You can use Ajax to submit your form data and show the image as well
something using jquery
'code'
$("#submitBtn").click

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to submit your form data and show the image as well

something using jquery

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
    $("#loadingImage").show(); //show the loading image
    $.post('/cgi-bin/upload.cgi',{yourdata}, {callback}) // submit your form, after the success of submission you can hide the image using hide() method
})
```

check more for $.post on jquery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) , Hope it helps!

Thanks,
Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Following code to page

<input type="Submit" value="submit" onclick="$('#loading').show();">

<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="loading.gif" alt="" /></div>
```